# How can I specify a row in awk in for loop?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I'm using the following `awk` command:

`my_command | awk -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR>1 {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]"`

which successfully returns my data like this:

```
fileName1
file Name 1
file Nameone
f i l e Name 1
```

So as you can see some file names have spaces.  This is fine as I'm just trying to echo the file name (nothing special).  The problem is calling that specific row within a loop.  I'm trying to do it this way:

```
i=1
for num in $rows
do
  fileName=$(my_command | awk -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==$i {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]])"
  echo "$num $fileName"
  $((i++))
done
```

But my output is always `null`

I've also tried using `awk -v record=$i` and then printing `$record` but I get the below results.

```
f i l e Name 1
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the confusion:  `rows` is a variable that list ids like this `11 12 13`
and each one of those ids ties to a file name.  My command without doing any parsing looks like this:

```
     id      File Info      OS
     11      File Name1     OS1
     12      Fi leNa me2    OS2
     13      FileName 3     OS3
```

I can only use the `id` field to run a the command that I need, but I want to use the `File Info` field to notify the user of the actual `File` that the command is being executed against.

Comment: Why do you pass the output my_command back into the input of it -- or is that a posting typo?

Comment: that's a typo!  thx..

Comment: Running awk over the whole file every time through the loop just to extract one line is awfully inefficient.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkReed I need to retrieve a list of fileNames using `my_command` and then tie a fileName to a num from a different command.

Comment: @MarkReed I see what you mean.  Thank you for that suggestion!

Comment: Start Again. Post your input and expected output and be clear. For example, when you say "My command..." are you talking about your tool named `my_command` or the whole script that calls the tool `my_command`. When you run the tool `my_command`, is it outputing excatly the same thing every time through the loop? Given your posted input and expected output there seems to be no point at all to the loop so why do you need it?

Comment: Actually, you'd be better of just posting a new question since you got an answer to your original question. You really should get help with the bigger picture though to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `$i` does not expand as expected. You should quote your arguments this way:

```
  fileName=$(my_command | awk -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" "NR==$i {print \$2}" | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]")
```

And you forgot the other `)`.

**EDIT**

As an update to your requirement you could just pass the rows to a single awk command instead of a repeatitive one inside a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROWS=(11 12)

function my_command {
    # This function just emulates my_command and should be removed later.
    echo "     id      File Info      OS
     11      File Name1     OS1
     12      Fi leNa me2    OS2
     13      FileName 3     OS3"
}

awk -- '
    BEGIN {
        input = ARGV[1]
        while (getline line < input) {
            sub(/^ +/, "", line)
            split(line, a, /   +/)
            for (i = 2; i < ARGC; ++i) {
                if (a[1] == ARGV[i]) {
                    printf "%s %s\n", a[1], a[2]
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        exit
    }
' <(my_command) "${ROWS[@]}"
```

That awk command could be condensed to one line as:

```
awk -- 'BEGIN { input = ARGV[1]; while (getline line < input) { sub(/^ +/, "", line); split(line, a, /   +/); for (i = 2; i < ARGC; ++i) { if (a[1] == ARGV[i]) {; printf "%s %s\n", a[1], a[2]; break; }; }; }; exit; }' <(my_command) "${ROWS[@]}"
```

Or better yet just use Bash instead as a whole:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROWS=(11 12)

while IFS=$' ' read -r LINE; do
    IFS='|' read -ra FIELDS <<< "${LINE//  +( )/|}"
    for R in "${ROWS[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${FIELDS[0]} == "$R" ]]; then
            echo "${R} ${FIELDS[1]}"
            break
        fi
    done
done < <(my_command)
```

It should give an output like:

```
11 File Name1
12 Fi leNa me2
```

Comment: Thanks, some weird things happened when I did the auto formatting...  I'm going to try your suggestions now.

Comment: You should also remove the `$` in `$((i++))` since you don't really intend to expand that to another command anyway but just increment the variable.

Comment: @inquisitor You could check my added solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Shell variables aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings. Use the `-v` option to set an awk variable to the shell variable:

```
fileName=$(my_command | awk -v i=$i -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==i {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]])"
```

This method avoids having to escape all the `$` characters in the `awk` script, as required in konsolebox's answer.

Comment: I actually thought about that only that I found the quoting simpler than adding another variable with another argument. For more complex solution `-v` would be a preference. Other than that it could be anyone's.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty inefficient to rerun `my_command` (and `awk`) every time through the loop just to extract one line from its output.  Especially when all you're doing is printing out part of each line in order. (I'm assuming that `my_command` really is exactly the same command and produces the same output every time through your loop.)

If that's the case, this one-liner should do the trick:

```
paste -d' ' <(printf '%s\n' $rows) <(my_command | 
  awk -F '[[:space:]]{2,}+' '($2 ~ /^[::alnum::]/) {print $2}')
```

Comment: `rows` is a variable that contains a list of ids I need to tie together with a specific `fileNames`.

Comment: then it would need to be `$rows` (or, if it's an array, `"${rows[@]}"`).

Answer (score 1):

As you already heard, you need to populate an awk variable from your shell variable to be able to use the desired value within the awk script so thi:

```
awk -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==$i {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]"
```

should be this:

```
awk -v i="$i" -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==i {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]"
```

Also, though, you don't need awk AND grep since awk can do anything grep van do so you can change this part of your script:

```
awk -v i="$i" -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" 'NR==i {print $2}' | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]"
```

to this:

```
awk -v i="$i" -F "[[:space:]]{2,}+" '(NR==i) && ($2~/^[[:alnum:]]/){print $2}'
```

and you don't need a `+` after a numeric range so you can change `{2,}+` to just `{2,}`:

```
awk -v i="$i" -F "[[:space:]]{2,}" '(NR==i) && ($2~/^[[:alnum:]]/){print $2}'
```

Most importantly, though, instead of invoking awk once for every invocation of `my_command`, you can just invoke it once for all of them, i.e. instead of this (assuming this does what you want):

```
i=1
for num in rows
do
  fileName=$(my_command | awk -v i="$i" -F "[[:space:]]{2,}" '(NR==i) && ($2~/^[[:alnum:]]/){print $2}')
  echo "$num $fileName"
  $((i++))
done
```

you can do something more like this:

```
for num in rows
do
  my_command
done |
awk -F '[[:space:]]{2,}' '$2~/^[[:alnum:]]/{print NR, $2}'
```

I say "something like" because you don't tell us what "my_command", "rows" or "num" are so I can't be precise but hopefully you see the pattern. If you give us more info we can provide a better answer.